# How to use different orientation for axis label in a parallel coordinate chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am giving a try to a "parallel coordinate" chart, and I have pretty much what I want, but I am at loss in term of defining different orientations for axis labels.
I need the labels to be all oriented to the right, except for the first one.
I probably have to add a axis variable to my "dimensions", but I am not sure how to do that.

```
var dimensions = [
  {
    name: "name",
    scale: d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, height]),
    type: String
  },
```

If someone could take a look at the code, that would be great.
Plunker here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/BgKBgANoMDV3123iQ9sP?p=preview

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is creating 2 different y axes:

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("right");

var yAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("left");
```

And then, calling the "left" one just for the first axis:

```
  dimension.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .each(function(d,i) { 
          if(i==0){
              d3.select(this).call(yAxis2.scale(d.scale)); 
          } else {
              d3.select(this).call(yAxis.scale(d.scale));
          }
      })
```

Here is your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/vzNHr6mvAVeX7J4PAnf6?p=preview